# How can I open Exchange Management Console 2007 from the "Run" dialog on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2007, emc

I need to know the path and filename to execute in order to open Exchange Management Console. Exchange Server 2007 is installed, and this server is running Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Exchange Management Console.msc". The quotes are needed.

The full path should be: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V12\Bin\Exchange Management Console.msc"

I am running Exchange 2010 and the path for me is:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\Exchange Management Console.msc"

Comment: Exchange 2010 adds the %ExchangeInstallPath% environment variable so you can also use that to make sure it works no matter where Exchange is installed.